# Unable to install latest version of a package that is in the NPM repo

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I'm having issues with a NPM and couple of dependencies where the latest version of a package that NPM finds is different from the latest version that is actually present in the NPM repo.

I'm trying to install a package that has other dependencies, but I'm unable to because I get the **"No matching version found for (package)@(version)"** error. However, if I go to the NPM official site, I can see that there is in fact matching version for the package I need.

I've upgraded NPM to its latest version and I have also cleaned my NPM cache.

Edit: Some of the specific packages in question - gulp-chmod@^2.0.0, sanitize-filename@^1.6.1, generator-code@1.1.22

Comment: What's the specific package and version?

Comment: it's very abstract question. Mention the version and package name respectively.

Comment: It's a couple of packages/dependencies  that are giving me the same problem. A few: gulp-chmod@^2.0.0, sanitize-filename@^1.6.1, generator-code@1.1.22, all of which exist on npm with those versions.

Comment: What's your node/npm version?

Comment: NPM version is 5.6.0 and node version is 6.11.3

Answer (score 0):

See if the adding the following key in **package.json** helps you!

```
"engines": {
  "node": "8.1.1",
  "npm": "5.0.3"
}
```

We can specify the node and npm version in the package.json file as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

In getting the same error (for a package I just updated, `typeson`) and looking at my log, I see it is trying to access:

> https://registry.npmjs.org/typeson

While this and https://www.npmjs.com/package/typeson are showing only up to 5.17.0, http://registry.npmjs.org/-/v1/search?text=typeson is showing the currently latest version, 5.18.0.

Maybe it can just take time to propagate through the site.

**Update:** In my case, it still wasn't working about an hour later, so I published a new version, and it was then immediately available.